# MySQL detect whether a field is empty or not

Tags: mysql

I have a large database consisting of multiple columns. I want to select one column that is of a small size and check whether another column that is of a very large size (measured in bytes) is null or empty. Of course I could just select them both and let the server-sided scripting language decide whether the second column is empty or not, but I really do not need the data of the second column, I only want to know if it is non null and non empty.

Now, since I'm not a MySQL ninja or anything, I am not sure if there is a possibility in MySQL to only select the "non-emptiness" of a column, and if this speeds things up when handling large columns. I ask this because I can imagine that MySQL handles these cases internally very differently, since there is no need for large amounts of disk reading, memory copying, piping to the server-sided script interpreter, etc. for the large second column, when only requesting a Boolean about its emptiness.

So

1. is it possible to only select the non-emptiness of a column and
2. does that speed up the query when that column is of significant size?

**I do not want to filter by it, rather I just want to get a column containing an entry true/false, depending on whether the large column is non-empty, for every row.**

Thank you very much in advance for taking the effort to read and answer this. If this has been answered before and I failed to find that answer, please let me know in the comments with a link and I'll remove this question immediately.

Comment: Just use a `CASE WHEN col1 IS NULL OR col1='' THEN do something END`

Comment: @Mihai I do not want to filter. Please see the edited version. Sorry that I was unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in SQL:

```
SELECT small_column
FROM   my_table
WHERE  large_column IS NULL OR LENGTH(large_column) = 0
```

EDIT:
To answer the question in the comment, you can put expressions in the select list:

```
SELECT small_column, 
       (large_column IS NULL OR LENGTH(large_column) = 0) AS
           is_large_column_empty
FROM   my_table
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it does not address my question. I think I was unclear in explaining what I want exactly. Please see the edited version of my question (the bold styled paragraph).

Comment: Thank you. That is what I wanted. And this is indeed significantly faster for large columns as I suggested?

Comment: @Jori You'd need to benchmark with your database and application, but generally speaking, it should be - you're saving passing a large column over the network.

Comment: Over the network? I was more thinking in terms of memory copying, disk searches, data piping, etc. Nothing should be passed over a network connection. It all happens on the server machine. I'm confused a bit now by what you mean :-).

Comment: If the database and "application server" run on the same machine (which is usually not recommended), you're right - network isn't an issue. But sure, memory and data piping are the issue here, and using this sort of technique will reduce both.